# Sumar valores columnas en c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

Tengo una tabla donde relleno los valores de cada columna de esta forma:

```
    columna = new TableCell();
    int jugadoresc = actual.NumeroJugadores;
    int equiposc = actual.EquiposActivos;
    if (jugadoresc!=0 && equiposc!=0) {
        columna.Text = ((Convert.ToSingle(actual.NumeroJugadores) / actual.EquiposActivos).ToString("N", conversor));
    }
    else
    {
        columna.Text = "0";
    }
    columna.Width = new Unit(30);
    fila.Cells.Add(columna);
```

Donde actual coge el valor dela fila correspondiente. Mi idea es sumar los valores de todas esas columnasy guardarlo/mostrarlo en una variable.

Un saludo y muchas gracias de antemano.

```
  protected TableRow FilaEvento(ClubDeportivo actual, int indice)
   {
    TableRow fila = new TableRow();
    TableCell columna;


    List<ClubDeportivo> cargadas = (List<ClubDeportivo>)Session["ListaClubsEdicion"];

    NumberFormatInfo conversor = new NumberFormatInfo();
    conversor.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
    conversor.NumberGroupSeparator = "";
    conversor.NumberDecimalDigits = 3;
    conversor.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 3;

    switch (indice % 2)
    {
        case 0:
            fila.CssClass = "filaPar";
            break;
        case 1:
            fila.CssClass = "filaImpar";
            break;
    }

    MySqlConnection conexion = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gestionTienda"].ConnectionString);
    conexion.Open();
    MySqlDataReader lector = null;

    if (cargadas.Count == 1)
    {
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT * from registro_entradas where empresa=@CodigoClub order by hora_entrada desc limit 1,1;", conexion);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoClub", actual.Codigo);
        lector = comando.ExecuteReader();



    }
    else
    {
        MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT * from registro_entradas where empresa=@CodigoClub order by hora_entrada desc limit 1;", conexion);
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CodigoClub", actual.Codigo);
        lector = comando.ExecuteReader();

    }

    List<string> codigos = new List<string>();


    //  lector.Close();
    columna = new TableCell();
    columna.Text = (indice + 1).ToString();
    fila.Cells.Add(columna);

    columna = new TableCell();
    columna.Text = actual.FechaDeAlta;
    fila.Cells.Add(columna);
    if (lector.Read())
    {
        columna = new TableCell();
        columna.Text = lector.GetDateTime("hora_entrada").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        fila.Cells.Add(columna);
        //  lector.Close();
        DateTime fechaEntrada = lector.GetDateTime("hora_entrada");
        DateTime fechaSalida = lector.GetDateTime("hora_salida");
        var horas = (fechaSalida - fechaEntrada).ToString(@"hh\h\ mm\m\ ss\s\ ");
        var diassinentrar = (DateTime.Now - fechaEntrada).ToString("dd");
        columna = new TableCell();
        columna.Text = diassinentrar;
        fila.Cells.Add(columna);
        lector.Close();
    }

    else
    {

        columna = new TableCell();
        columna.Text = "SIN ACCESOS";
        columna.CssClass = "sinaccesos";
        fila.Cells.Add(columna);
        //  lector.Close();
        columna = new TableCell();
        columna.Text = "SIN ACCESOS";
        columna.CssClass = "sinaccesos";
        fila.Cells.Add(columna);
        lector.Close();
    }



    columna = new TableCell();
    columna.Text = actual.Nombre;
    fila.Cells.Add(columna);
    columna = new TableCell();
    columna.Text = actual.Poblacion;
    fila.Cells.Add(columna);
    columna = new TableCell();
    columna.Text = actual.EquiposActivos.ToString();
    fila.Cells.Add(columna);

    columna = new TableCell();
    columna.Text = actual.NumeroJugadores.ToString();
    fila.Cells.Add(columna);

    columna = new TableCell();
    int jugadoresc = actual.NumeroJugadores;
    int equiposc = actual.EquiposActivos;
    if (jugadoresc!=0 && equiposc!=0) {
        columna.Text = ((Convert.ToSingle(actual.NumeroJugadores) / actual.EquiposActivos).ToString("N", conversor));
    }
    else
    {
        columna.Text = "0";
    }
    columna.Width = new Unit(30);
    fila.Cells.Add(columna);



        columna = new TableCell();
        columna.Text = actual.TipoContrato;
        columna.CssClass = "contrato" + actual.TipoContrato;
        fila.Cells.Add(columna);



        columna = new TableCell();
        columna.CssClass = "central";
        columna.Text = actual.NoticiasTotales.ToString();
        columna.Width = new Unit(30);
        fila.Cells.Add(columna);

        int dias = (DateTime.Now - FuncionesApoyo.TxtFecha(actual.FechaDeAlta)).Days;
        columna = new TableCell();
        columna.CssClass = "central";
        columna.Text = dias.ToString();
        columna.Width = new Unit(30);
        fila.Cells.Add(columna);

        columna = new TableCell();
        columna.CssClass = "central";

        if (dias != 0)
        {

            columna.Text = ((Convert.ToSingle(actual.NoticiasTotales) / dias) * 30.0f).ToString("N", conversor);

        }


        else
        {
            columna.Text = "0";


        }
        columna.Width = new Unit(30);
        fila.Cells.Add(columna);
    lector.Close();
    conexion.Close();

    return fila;
}
```

Explico de una forma más detallada. Tengo algo como esto:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los títulos de las columnas los tengo creados pero no puse el codigo. El código que puse es la forma en que relleno cada fila, donde actual coge el club de esa fila y muestra sus datos dependiendo de la variable que le asigne. Mi idea es sumar por ejemplo todos los ratios de la misma columna para hacer una media global.

Comment: a que "todas" esas columnas haces referencia? alli solo veo que signas el valor a una sola, cuales son las otras? porque creas un TableCell ? o sea que componente se trata? de donde sale "actual" porque quizas no necesites para la suma hacer la operacion en ese punto sino puedes sumar la coleccion original que usas para generar la tabla

Comment: TableCell es cada columna. Tengo varias columnas creadas de la misma forma, que luego la añado como veis a la fila correspondiente. Mi idea es hacer una media de los vvalores de esa columna que he puesto. Actual sale de la clase donde cargo todos los datos de una tabla de la base de datos. Pongo toda la función arriba.

Comment: la verdad esta bastante feo el codigo que nos muestra, porque no usaste un GridView? no veo que es lo que estas iterando, solo como creas una fila, pero cuales son los datos?

Comment: cual es el objetivo de `if (cargadas.Count == 1)` ? lo que no queda claro que lista es la que usas para generar la tabla

Comment: Lo de if(cargadas.count==1) para eso no tiene nada que ver. Solo lo hago para hacer una consulta u otra dependiendo del tipo de usuario y a que datos tiene acceso.

Comment: cual es la lista que usas para generar la tabla ? porque la sumas la realizas en base a esta, no cuando iteras en la generacion de la fila

Comment: La lista es esta:  List<ClubDeportivo> cargadas = (List<ClubDeportivo>)Session["ListaClubsEdicion"];

Comment: bien tienes la lista, pero que es lo que quieres sumar? porque en el codigo que nos muestras creas varias celdas que no logro entender por todo el calculo que le agregas

Comment: He editado un poco más el post y poniendo una imagen sobre como se vea, para que sea más entendible, que igual en su momento no me expliqué suficientemente bien. Muchas gracias por todo.

Comment: que te impide sumar a medida que vas agregando el dato a la grilla?

Answer (score 2):

Si cuentas con una lista puedes sumar directamente usando esta junto con `linq` en lugar de iterar mientras crear la prepresentaicon de la tabla

Entonces para sumar el ratio seria algo como

```
List<ClubDeportivo> cargadas = (List<ClubDeportivo>)Session["ListaClubsEdicion"];

decimal ratio = cargadas.Sum(x=> {
                          int dias = (DateTime.Now - FuncionesApoyo.TxtFecha(actual.FechaDeAlta)).Days;
                          return (Convert.ToSingle(actual.NoticiasTotales) / dias) * 30.0f;
                 });
```

usando el `Sum` de linq puedes definir la formula que calule el ratio de cada row sumando todos los valores

Comment: Esto esta bien.. pero no estaria haciendo dos veces el mismo trabajo? digo, si recorre lo que sea que recorre para generar la grilla a mano, ya paso por las celdas que quiere sumar.. porque no suma directamente al agregar a la grilla?

Comment: es que para generar la tabla no deberias estar recorriendo nada, para eso existe el GridView y si hay calculos usas linq, por eso mencione al principio que generar las rows creando TableCell desde codigo no esta bueno

Comment: Ponelo en la respuesta tambien!! que en los comentarios se pierde..

Comment: He hecho eso como comentas, y al mostrar el resultado me sale NaN. Vamos que se ve que falla el tipo de formato del número supongo.

Comment: si puede ser, no valide las conversiones de tipo, solo me base en lo que tenias, quizas falte algun cast a decimal o quizas cambiar el float por otro tipo